# Can reading data from an nfc tag raise different intents based on whether a certain app is installed?

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

I'm considering writing an app which would perform a certain function based on the data held in an NFC tag which it is reading.

However I would also like it that if the first time the tag was scanned and the app wasn't installed that android would take the user to the apps location in the play store.

I understand that you can encode a url in the NFC tag which could direct to the play store but after the app is installed how would I then pick up the extra information?

Is it even possible?

Thanks, 
M

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two actions on one NFC tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19402435/two-actions-on-one-nfc-tag)

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#aar, but I am not sure