# Can I program an RFID tag to present natively-actionable data to a smartphone (such as a URL), alongside other custom data?

Tags: android, nfc, rfid, ndef, core-nfc

I've learned that the NFC tag spec offers a few standardized formats (plain text, e-mail, Wi-Fi SSID, business card data, URL, etc.) that compatible phones are capable of natively responding to simply by enabling NFC functionality in OS settings.

Am I correct in understanding that no 3rd-party app installation is needed for this to function? Does this invariant hold true for both Android and iOS 11+? I see that iPhone 7 and up supports Core NFC.

**If the above is true**, my actual question follows.

---

I have an application to display some data from an RFID chip that would be deployed with moderate ubiquity.

Under normal circumstances, a dedicated app would be used to fetch and display this data, to guarantee consistency (everything's always in the same place) along with presentational clarity.

However, in rare situations, the devices (phones) scanning the RFID tags may not have the reader app installed. They may also not have any cellular connectivity, making app installation difficult. (This is a rare/unlikely but plausible edge-case.)

In such a scenario, would it be possible for the tag to deliver a "natively-actionable" piece of information to the phone, such as a plaintext fragment of data, similar to how NFC tags work?

It would be great if I could offer a URL and also a text fragment. [Two actions on one NFC tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19402435/two-actions-on-one-nfc-tag) suggests this *may* be doable but it sounds like it's a hack exploiting undefined behavior (?).

---

The RFID tag itself does not need much onboard capacity; the maximum capability required would be retrieving a few hundred bytes of data that is occasionally overwritten. Some read and write counters would probably be the only other feature required.

Answer (score 0):

Android devices will usually handle a few data types automatically using built-in apps. E.g. URLs are shown/opened by default without the need for a 3rd party app. Core NFC on iOS does not seem to have such a capability. NFC tags can only be read when an app explicitly starts reading.

It's possible to put multiple NDEF records on one tag. For Android, you would need to make sure that the *first* record can trigger an automatic action (i.e. is a URL) or that *any* record is an Android Application Record. [Two actions on one NFC tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19402435/2425802) is certianly not a hack but exactly the way to do this.